# keep 'vlc -I dummy' running when invoked from bash script via launcher

Tags: linux, bash, signals, vlc, launcher

Say I have the following bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

addrss="mms://enleuko.live24.gr/enleuko877"
echo -n "addr: "
read uaddr
[[ -n $uaddr ]] && addrss=$uaddr
vlc -I dymmy --quiet $addrss &
exit 0
```

The above runs on ttys and the xterminal and **keeps running** even if I logout or close the window. If I try to invoke it by a launcher like the following though, it kills `vlc` when my script exits.

```
[Desctop Entry]
Name=enleuko
Icon=icon
Exec=radio
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Categories=Network;
```

*note that my script has a `read` statement so i need the `Terminal=true` value.

I've read as much as I could about `trap`, `disown`, `nohup` and I've tried a number of combinations but nothing helped me much..
I thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this really impossible?! I don't understand that behavior. I modified my script to `printenv` and the results where identical when i invoked my script from `xterminal` and from the `launcher`. Still when i closed the `xterminal` vlc wasn't killed!

Comment: What is the use of `eval` there?

Comment: @X.Jacobs None... I don't even remember why I put it there in the first place..! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `nohup`?

```
  nohup vlc -I dymmy --quiet $addrss &
```

Alternatively, you could remove the fork process operator "&" of your original vlc command.